# JsonAPI SuiteCRM pulling back multiple records

Tags: json-api, suitecrm

I am currently doing a suitecrm implementation and my client has the requirement of pulling back all prospects that belong to a specific prospect list programmatically.

In suitecrm getting a list of prospects is easy

GET: /module/api/v8/Prospects

Also getting the prospect lists are simple

GET: /module/api/v8/Prospect_Lists

However, in the JSON API Spec, the relationship exists by calling an API to provide you with a list of related objects, for example
GET: /Api/V8/module/ProspectLists/a8f704d4-c25b-53e6-a7fc-6005b93835cd/relationships/prospects
Returns an array of prospect Id's that are related to the Prospect_List.
Example response:

```
{
  {
  "data": [
        {
            "type": "Prospect",
            "id": "9c3d7edf-9679-eff3-9ff0-60197fe7af68",
            "links": {
                "self": "V8/module/Prospect/9c3d7edf-9679-eff3-9ff0-60197fe7af68"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Prospect",
            "id": "d4ab2b49-c95d-9a64-4770-601c2b658adf",
            "links": {
                "self": "V8/module/Prospect/d4ab2b49-c95d-9a64-4770-601c2b658adf"
            }
        },
           ]

}
```

My question is, with the JSON Api (Specifically suitecrm) is it possible to pull back all the related records (the full records, not just the ID's) in one shot rather than loop through the array and do get requests one by one?

I did test using the filter parameter which does not seem to do the trick and scares me anyway because of the variable length nature of the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

You question contains of two parts:

1. Linking related resources in JSON:API specification
2. Implementation of JSON:API specification in SuiteCRM

Let me answer them one after the other.

### Linking related resources in JSON:API specification

The JSON:API specification defines to links for relationships:

1. Relationship Links
2. Related Resource Links

They may be included in the `links` member of a [relationship object](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships). The `self` key provides the Relationship Link. The `related` key provides the Related Resource Link.

A Relationship Link is defined as "a link for the relationship itself. This link allows the client to directly manipulate the relationship. [...] When fetched successfully, this link returns the linkage for the related resources as its primary data." ([Source](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships))

[Resource Linkage](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage) mentioned in the definition is the [Resource Identifier Objects](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-identifier-objects) of the related resource (has-one relationship) or resources (has-many relationship). A Resource Identifier Object is the unique combination of `type` and `id` of a specific resource, which identifies it.

A [Related Resource Link](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-related-resource-links) "provides access to resource objects linked in a relationship. When fetched, the related resource object(s) are returned as the response’s primary data."

To summarize for `GET` operations:

1. Relationship Links provides `type` and `id` of related resource or resources.
2. Related Resource Links provides the full resource objects of the related resources.

It's up to the implementation of both, a Relationship Link and a Related Resource Link, is provided for a specific relationship, only one of them or none.

### Implementation of JSON:API specification in SuiteCRM

I don't have experience with SuiteCRM API myself. All information provided are based on public documentation [Suite CRM API V8](https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/api/developer-setup-guide/json-api/) and the information provided in your question.

SuiteCRM provides an example response of a request to get a single resource:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "Account",
        "id": "11a71596-83e7-624d-c792-5ab9006dd493",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "White Cross Co",
            "account_type": "Customer"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "AOS_Contracts": {
                "links": {
                    "related": "/V8/module/Accounts/11a71596-83e7-624d-c792-5ab9006dd493/relationships/aos_contracts"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The resource object for the `Account` with ID `11a71596-83e7-624d-c792-5ab9006dd493` includes a Related Resource Link for the `AOS_Contracts` relationship. It is `/V8/module/Accounts/11a71596-83e7-624d-c792-5ab9006dd493/relationships/aos_contracts`.

The response you included would not be what I would expect from a Related Resource Link. It does not include any fields of the `Prospect` resources. It looks like Resource Identifier Objects with additional self link.

I don't think this is wrong strictly speaking. The JSON:API specification allows the server to include only a subset of all fields in the response by default. That subset may be different depending on the endpoint. But it's at least very uncommon.

In that case you should be able to request inclusion of specific fields using [Sparse Fieldsets](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets) feature. I don't know the fields of `Prospect` resource in SuiteCRM. But assuming it has a `name` attribute, you could request to include it (and only it) with adding these query parameter to the Related Resource Link: `?fields[Prospect]=name`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The question was how to pull child records without iteration, I.E. retrieving a list of objects filtered by a parent id.  It does not seem possible (at least using suitecrm). There is a filter attribute in JSON:API, but then you are gambling on never maxing out the URL length.  I ended up solving it by giving up on JSON:API and hitting the database directly for this specific dataset.

Comment: I tried to answer that question. A Related Resource Link should provide you a list of all resource objects for a given relationship. If an implementation returns a list of Resource Identifier Objects (`type` and `id` only) it seems to be a bug. If you could include the relevant requests with their response I may be able to call out more clearly if and how SuiteCRM implements JSON:API specification in a strange way. Or are you aware of any public SuiteCRM API I can use for testing myself?

Comment: Assuming the `/Api/V8/module/ProspectLists/a8f704d4-c25b-53e6-a7fc-6005b93835cd/relationships/prospects` URL mentioned in your question was given as a `related` link in a relationship and it returns the payload included in your question, I would call it at least a very strange implementation of JSON:API specification. It may not violate the spec by word. But it does violate its intend for sure. You may be able to work-a-round that implementation using Sparse Fieldsets, which [seem to be supported](https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/api/developer-setup-guide/json-api/#_fields) by SuiteCRM.

Comment: I don't know of any public open API's, I installed it locally for testing.   I would agree that the implementation is strange. I tested the sparse field sets thing, and it seems that they only allow field selection for data included within the current set, meaning you cannot reach out to related objects.  I think I found an acceptable workaround.  Thanks for the help though!